# mailman not relaying email to external address

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, ubuntu-12.04, mailman

I have a setup of mailman with postfix on an ubuntu server 12.04.
My problem is that mailing list emails are *not* forwarded to email addresses external to my institution. However

- the initial welcome email is received by everyone, internally and externally.
- in fact, a simple email from command line with `mail` is successfully sent to anyone
- after that, mailing list emails are only forwarded to internal addresses.
- the domain name I'm using for the server is *not* that of my institution who is hosting the server.

Here is my `main.cf`:

```
#myorigin  = sub.myinstitution.tld
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/16 # this is my institution ip range
relayhost = smtp.myinstitution.tld
#inet_interfaces = loopback-only
#local_transport = error:local delivery is disabled
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
myhostname = mywebsite.tld
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
#relay_domains = $mydestination, ecs.soton.ac.uk
```

I also found these two links on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/268472/mailman-cannot-relay-e-mails-to-non-local-domains) and [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11949603), but neither of these solutions seem to do the trick for me.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Output of `postconf -n`:

```
$ postconf -n
config_directory = /etc/postfix
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
myhostname = mywebsite.tld
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/16
myorigin = mywebsite.tld
relayhost = smtp.myinstitution.tld
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

I'm not sure what to post for the log. I can't see anything wrong there. This is what happens in `/var/log/mail.log` when I send a message:

```
Sep 29 10:23:19 mywebsite postfix/pickup[30113]: 3CD85E4382: uid=10785 from=<myuser>
Sep 29 10:23:19 mywebsite postfix/cleanup[30172]: 3CD85E4382: message-id=<20120929092319.3CD85E4382@mywebsite.tld>
Sep 29 10:23:19 mywebsite postfix/qmgr[30114]: 3CD85E4382: from=<myuser@mywebsite.tld>, size=338, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 29 10:23:19 mywebsite postfix/smtp[30174]: 3CD85E4382: to=<myuser@myinstitution.tld>, orig_to=<list>, relay=smtp.myinstitution.tld[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:25, delay=0.07, delays=0.04/0/0.01/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 q8T9Nap1028342 Message accepted for delivery)
Sep 29 10:23:19 mywebsite postfix/qmgr[30114]: 3CD85E4382: removed
```

Comment: You have to post any log entry containing the string "3CD85E4382". Otherwise it is like "My PC doesn't work. What to do?"

Comment: Done, I added everything that contains that string.

Comment: Your log shows the mail was succesfully sent to smtp.myinstitution.tld . Two op[tions : 1) this mail has been delivered sucessfully to myuser@myinstitution.tld then you have to post logs about an email that has a problem 2) myuser@myinstitution.tld did not receive the mail, then you have to keep on investigating on what happened on smtp.myinstitution.tld, or ask this server administrator.

Comment: It's true that myuser@myinstitution received the email. However, more email addresses are listed on that mailing list and they haven't received the mail (say myotheruser@gmail.com), nor this shows on the mail log. Does that suggest that it's a mailman configuration problem rather than a postfix one?

Answer (score 1):

*How* does mailman send email ? Does it always use the local sendmail(1) command, or does it also require SMTP to function ?

You have explicitly made SMTP impossible with `inet_interfaces = loopback_only`.

Please add the output from `postconf -n` and a log segment showing what goes wrong.

Comment: I tried commenting out that line, but it still doesn't work. I added more info to the question as you said. Not sure what to put for the log as I can't see anything going wrong. Can you see any other problem? Thanks for your help!